# List of words in A -> Query: When *word* in record (Table B), then populate xxx (Table B) with corresponding record of Table A

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use MS Access SQL.
I have two tables. TableA is like a dictionary (like word1 - groupe_one, word3 - group_two)
I want to create a Query in which all data of TableB is included, but also if the record belongs to any group, which is defined in TableA.

The only solution I found is not using a TabeA but instead use:
SWITCH(TableB.sentence like '*word1*', 'group_one', '*word2*', 'group_one')

However this only works to a certain degree and is not very easy to handle.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join on a condition that uses `LIKE`:

```
SELECT tb.sentence, ta.group
FROM tableA ta
INNER JOIN tableB tb ON (tb.sentence LIKE ('*' & ta.fragment & '*'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select b.*, a.group
from tableB as b, tableA as a  
where " " & b.sentence & " " like "* " & a.fragment & " *";
```

Notes:

- MS Access is finicky about inequalities in the `on` clause, so this is phrased using a cross join (and MS Access doesn't support `cross join`.
- The wildcard in MS Access is not the standard `'%'` but `'*'`.
- This adds spaces before and after the word and sentence to get a "word" match.